# BASH: Everything but not slash? IF STATEMENT (STRING COMPARISION)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to match any strings that start with `/John/` but does not contain `/` after `/John/`

```
if

  [ $string == /John/[!/]+ ]; then  ....

fi
```

This is what I got and it doesn't seem to be working.

So I tried

```
if

  [[ $string =~ ^/John/[!/]+$ ]]; then  ....

fi
```

It still didn't work, and so I changed it to

```
if

  [[ $string =~ /John/[^/] ]]; then  ....

fi
```

It worked but will match with all the strings that has `/` behind `/John/` too.

Answer (score 0):

For bash you want `[[ $string =~ /John/[^/]*$ ]]` -- the end-of-line anchor ensures there are no slashes after the last acceptable slash.

Answer (score 0):

How about "the string starts with '/John/' and doesn't contain any slashes after '/John/'"?

```
[[ $string = /John/* && $string != /John/*/* ]]
```

Or you could compare against a parameter expansion that only expands if the conditions are met. This says "after stripping off everything including and after the last slash, the string is /John":

```
[[ ${string%/*} = /John ]]
```

In fact, this last solution is the only entirely POSIXLY_STRICT one I can come up with without multiple `test` expressions.

```
[ "${string%/*}" = /John ]
```

By the way, your problem is probably simply be using double-equals inside a single-bracket `test` expression. bash actually does accept them inside *double*-bracket test expressions, but a single equals is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plain old grep:

```
string='/John Lennon/Yoko Ono'
if echo "$string" | grep -q "/John[^/]" ; then
    echo "matched"
else
    echo "no match found"
fi
```

This only fails if /John is at the very end of the string... if that's a possibility then you can tweak to handle that case, for instance:

```
string='/John Lennon/Yoko Ono'
if echo "$string" | grep -qP "(/John[^/])|(/John$)" ; then
    echo "matched"
else
    echo "no match found"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what language you're using, but normal negative character classes are prefixed with a ^

e.g.

```
[^/]
```

You can also put in start/end qualifiers (clojure example, so Java's regex engine). Usually ^ at beginning and $ at end.

```
user => (re-matches #"^/[a-zA-Z]+[^/]$" "/John/")
nil
```